# Tecla F6 envía error: Archivo de registro no encontrado

Tags: errors, compilation-error

Trato presionar la tecla F6 y en los tutoriales de YouTube los que hacen el video lo presionan y a todos les va bien, pero a mi no :(

Comment: This is an English language site. Can you please translate your question? It might also be useful to add further information to your question, for example which editor you are using.

Comment: The functionality of the F key are different from editor to editor, so we also need to know which editor you are using.

Comment: Buen día! manejo TeXworks

Comment: @JrAlvaroRodriguez I don't understand a single word. Please translate your question to English. Use a truthworthy translator if necessary.

Comment: @samcarter isn't that just the OP restating the question in english? This question should then be deleted

Comment: @daleif Yes, it's the same Q in English. I think creating a link to the new question will be advantageous for people who come across this in the close review queue and might otherwise postpone closing to give the OP time to fix this question, but because there is already a new version, it is not necessary to wait with closing